# Easy Chart UDT Parameter Passing

Tags: ignition, scada-ignition

Hello I am working on an ignition 8.1 project.  I am basically on my main vision client window have 10 machines and when I click on one of them it brings up a more detailed popup page on itself.  I got that to work and got all my other little components to work properly taking in my UDT parameters properly but when I try to do it to an easy chart its not populating properly.  I've tried thru the easy chart customizer and also under the property editor under the Tag pens.  The Tag pens I binded them to the UDT parameter for each pen but still nothing.  Anyone have any advice? [Pen Tag Binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxRLE.png)

I am expecting that when I click on machine 1 machine 1 easy chart historical data will show and so on for each machine properly on every popup.

Comment: Are you trying to pass the UDT itself? ...or are you passing the path as a string? Passing the UDT itself won't work. With a UDT, one approach that would work would be to pass the path as a custom propery in the popup as a string. A script on the internalFrameOpened event handler could then write the string value to the tag pens dataset.

Comment: Ok I'll look how to do that in the popup.  I'm guessing a script that runs when clicked to push values into the chart properly not the chart pointing at the UDT itself

Comment: I have created a tutorial on how to pass parameters to popups here: [Use only one window for different components values](https://forum.inductiveautomation.com/t/use-only-one-window-for-different-components-values/68062/8). If you look at the tagPens dataset property, you probably use this approach to simply pass the whole dataset. In this way scripting would not be necessary.